# Is QLoRA viable to train Falcon-7(40)B-instruct on a new language?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, fine-tuning, large-language-model

Hei, there. I've been researching the latest technologies, and I understand quite well(I hope I do) that (Q)LoRA is a viable option for finetuning LLMs on QA for specific tasks. I am still wondering if I could use the same technique to finetune an open LLM(I am not sure if Falcon models are the most suitable for this) on Romanian since my company has a lot of documents in Romanian and I would like the model to answer questions about them, and maybe produce new documents based on the ones it has seen during finetuning.

Firstly I would like to finetune it on Romanian, and then on the specific task(accounting questions in Romanian, legislation, rules, etc).

Can you guys please help me with some hints on how I would build my training datasets for the first part, and if this is an alright approach?